# Combining list of character vectors with different sizes into a single dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to combine a list of character vectors into a single data frame.  For example, I want

```r
list(A=c("123","456"), B=c("789"), C=c("000"))
```

to become:

```
  label val
1     A 123
2     A 456
3     B 789
4     C 000
```

I came up with the following.  It works, but it seems clunky.  Is there a more elegant way to do the above?

```r
l <- list(A=c("123","456"), B=c("789"), C=c("000"))
res <- lapply(names(l), function(x) { 
    data.frame(label=rep(x, length(l[[x]])), val=l[[x]], 
        stringsAsFactors = F) })
do.call("rbind", res)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use good old fashioned base R.

```
stack(l)
#   values ind
# 1    123   A
# 2    456   A
# 3    789   B
# 4    000   C
```

Comment: thanks! did not know about `stack()`;  I just figured out that `reshape2::melt` works as well.

Comment: reshape2 is crapy library. use tidyr instead

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- list(A=c("123","456"), B=c("789"), C=c("000"))
enframe(test, "label", "val") %>% unnest
```

Comment: what package is enframe/unnest?

Comment: @patrickmdnet I updated the answer